# How to type a circumflex over a greek letter in text mode?

Tags: accents, greek, text-mode

I am trying to type a circumflex over a Greek letter in `\chapter`. In particular, I'm using this package:

```
\usepackage{textgreek}
```

However, if I write `\^{\textPi}` I get this result:

[image]

while I want the circumfex to be over the letter. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  try removing the braces around `\textPi`.  i think it shouldn't make any difference, but i can't test it.

Comment: Thank for the answer, but I still get the same output.

Answer (score 4):

The `\^{\textPi}` construction cannot, unfortunately, work. Here's a workaround:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\greekhat}[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \^{}\cr
      \noalign{\kern-1ex}
      #1\cr
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A title with \greekhat{\textPi}}

And a \greekhat{\textPi} in text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Are you sure you don't want this in math mode, which would be `$\hat{\Pi}$`?

In my opinion, math shouldn't be emboldened if in titles, but you can do it.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A title with $\bm{\hat{\Pi}}$ or $\hat{\Pi}$}

And a $\hat{\Pi}$ in math as well.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, now it works.
I have already used $\hat{\Pi}$ in math mode but I needed something to write the same in \chapter.

Comment: @LeoB. I'm not sure why it should be different. I added something.